# how to use highcharts in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in highcharts. I try to use it in my asp.net MVC 4 project. I want to pass information relative to charts from controller to view. I've used session to pass differents categories, the chart appear but without categories. Is there any solution to pass information from controller to view?

this is part of my code:

view:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $('#divStat').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: ''
                },
                xAxis: {

                    categories: '@Session["affiche"]',
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                      [...]
                 });

    </script>
```

controller:

```
    public ActionResult Stat()  
    {            
         String[] list = new String[5];
         list[0] = "Africa";
         list[1] = "America";
         list[2] = "Asia";
         list[3] = "Europe";
         list[4] = "Oceania";             

         Session["affiche"] = list;

        return PartialView("Charts");
    }
```

Comment: https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/ has lot of examples in mvc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put ","  among the strings to make javascript understand that is an array

```
@{
     string[] theList = (string[])Session["affiche"];
     string javascriptArrayString = "";

     foreach(string str in theList){
         javascriptArrayString += "'"+ str +"',";
     }

     javascriptArrayString = javascriptArrayString.Substring(javascriptArrayString.Length,javascriptArrayString.Length-1);

}
```

then:

```
categories: [@javascriptArrayString],
```

and the html result will be like :

```
categories: ['Africa','Asia','America','Europe','Oceania'],
```

this is a bit rough coding , but i think you'll get the point.